# How do I extract username from the json.loads object

Tags: python, json, telegram-bot

I have a following block of code:

```
import json
from types import SimpleNamespace

data=json.dumps(
{
  "update_id": 992108054,
  "message": {
    "delete_chat_photo": False,
    "new_chat_members": [],
    "date": 1669931418,
    "photo": [],
    "entities": [],
    "message_id": 110,
    "group_chat_created": False,
    "caption_entities": [],
    "new_chat_photo": [],
    "supergroup_chat_created": False,
    "chat": {
      "type": "private",
      "first_name": "test_name",
      "id": 134839552,
      "last_name": "test_l_name",
      "username": "test_username"
    },
    "channel_chat_created": False,
    "text": "test_text",
    "from": {
      "last_name": "test_l_name",
      "is_bot": False,
      "username": "test_username",
      "id": 134839552,
      "first_name": "test_name",
      "language_code": "en"
    }
  }
})
x = json.loads(data, object_hook=lambda d: SimpleNamespace(**d))
print(x.message.text,
      x.message.chat
        )
```

Which works fine.
However, when I add

```
print(x.message.from)
```

I get an error:

```
 File "<ipython-input-179-dec1b9f9affa>", line 1
    print(x.message.from)
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Could you please help me? How can I access fields inside 'from' block?

Answer (score 0):

As `from` is a keyword, try this `x.message.__getattribute__('from')`:

```
>>> x.message.__getattribute__('from')
namespace(last_name='test_l_name',
          is_bot=False,
          username='test_username',
          id=134839552,
          first_name='test_name',
          language_code='en')
```

And to get one of its attribute, say `username`, you could access like what you have been doing:

```
>>> x.message.__getattribute__('from').username
'test_username'
```